# How to render Xaxes with time in hours, days, ... from 0 to infinity

Tags: highcharts, axis, axis-labels

I want to render multiples series with diferent time intervals, all series start for exemple en first day of the year and I want to see Xaxis for exemple:

```
-------------------------------------------------
0 12h 1day 36h 2days 60h
```

When I zooming betwen 36h to 60h I'd like to see Xaxis

```
-------------------------------------------------
36h 42h 48h 54h 60h
```

If I zooming more the last interval, I'd like to see Xaxis

```
-------------------------------------------------
48h 46:05 46:06 46:07 46:08 46:09
```

and more

```
-------------------------------------------------
46:07:00 46:08:00 46:09:00
```

I have this link for testing
xAxis type datetime

[Example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmsalai/8favdnoq/7/)

```js
xAxis: {
    //visible: false,
title: {
    enabled: false,
    text: 'Hours of the Day'
},
type: 'datetime',

    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
      second: '%H:%M:%S',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M:%S',//'%H:%M',
      day: '24:00', // %e. %b',
      week: '%e. %b',
      month: '%b \'%y',
      year: '%Y'
    }
},
```

Can anybody help me how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably use Highstock. It offers better management of datetime charts.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by mapping the data array and reducing each element timestamp by the first element timestamp. Then your data will start from 0 and will be relative to the first element.

**Code:**

```
  const reduce = data[0].x;

  series: [{
    data: data.map(elem => {
      elem.x = elem.x - reduce;
      return elem;
    })
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2ubce48g/

Comment: Thank you for the example !!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much !!

But the time axis is only 24h, can be 25h, 26h, .... 56h, .....70h

[An exemple of more than 24h time Axis](https://jsfiddle.net/jmsalai/03Lcad8k/)

```
xAxis: {
//visible: false,
title: {
  enabled: false,
  text: 'Hours of the Day'
},
type: 'datetime',

dateTimeLabelFormats: {
  millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
  second: '%H:%M:%S',
  minute: '%H:%M',
  hour: '%H:%M',
  day: '%H:%M',
  week: '%e. %b',
  month: '%b \'%y',
  year: '%Y'
}
```

},

Thanks !